# How to loop through a CSV with multiple lines to grab 2 variables?

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have a CSV file that contains usernames and passwords. The file looks something like this:

```
user1,password1
user2,password2
user3,password3
```

I need to loop through each line to grab the username and password, use those variables, and then grab the next set of usernames and passwords, replace the content of the variables with the new ones, etc.

I've been searching for the best way to do this, but I'm not very familiar scripting and I'm getting lost. I've used `awk` to grab both individually, but I'm struggling to figure out how to use `awk` within a while loop. And I'm reading that might not be a great approach.

Comment: You need to be very explicit about your requirements. What dows "replace the content of the variables" mean? Do you need to modify the file, or is the new value only relevant for the duration of the running program?

Comment: Can the passwords contain commas? If yes, how would they be encoded if at all?

Comment: The right answer all depends on what you mean by `use those variables` - if you post some concise, testable sample input **and expected output** then we can help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any need for awk here:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r user pass; do
  # something with "$user" "$pass"
done < path/to/file.csv
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I tried read, but I couldn't figure out how to separate by the comma. Thanks again!

Comment: If `use those variables` from the question means `call a tool` or `move a file` or similar that requires manipulating files or processes than that's not a terrible approach but if it means `change value x to y` or similar that just requires manipulating text then that would be a terrible approach (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) so hopefully the OP understands the difference,

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have some pretty good passwords:

```
user1,",3 ""e`$^~´"
user2,""")& Eu`id`"
user3,ThisIsAlsoAGoodPasswordBecauseItIsLong
```

Then you need something that can parse CSV ("" inside " is a ").

```
cat user+password.csv | parallel --csv do_stuff {1} {2}
```

Comment: One of these days, we'll find something that `parallel` can't do... ;P More seriously though, does `parallel` really need you to `cat` the file? That feels like a UUoC, is there no other way?

Comment: @terdon You know there are plenty of other ways :)

Comment: Funnily enough, those passwords are no longer secure because they are available online. also, is the `do_stuff` a function? A command/alias? Or something else?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel True. It works directly if it is a command. If it a function or an alias you use `env_parallel` instead of `parallel`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, the password also ends up being passed as argument to a shell and to do_stuff, which at least in the case of the shell, means it will be exposed in the output of `ps`.

Comment: @OleTange Do you think it is a good fit for this question to add the `env_parallel` information?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Interesting ... But it's not as bad as using a password from a website accessible to everybody. But I didn't knew it would should in `ps`. Though it would just show the `cat` :/

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a proper CSV file, you can use `ksh93` instead of `bash` which has support for parsing CSVs:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ksh93
while IFS=, read -rS user password; do
  something with "$user" and "$password"
done
```

On an input like

```
user,"a""b
c,d"
```

That would correctly set `$user` to `user` and `$password` to `a"b<LF>c,d`.

Comment: How do you enter a password containing newline?

Comment: @OleTange, that very much depends on the interface that inputs those passwords if any. For instance, if the password is retrieved as an environment variable, that can be `PASSWORD=$'a"b\nc,d' some-command`. With basic HTTP authentication, newline would be base64 encoded like any other character. In any case, that's hardly relevant to this Q&A.